# Keep height of row locked

Tags: excel, vba, row-height

I have row 1 where I am keeping my command buttons for my worksheet ("Xman"). I am having a difficult time keeping the the height. As soon as I have any activity on the worksheet it auto adjusts for the standard row height. Is there a way I can make the following VBA permanent by always keeping it. Not very efficient to constantly adjust the height to get to the command buttons. Thank you,

```
Sub Rowheight()
Rows("1:1").Rowheight = 70

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling "Wrap Text" with the entire row selected.

[Wrap Text button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJRbt.png)

You may have to press the button a couple of times to ensure it's disabled for the entire row (the button should not be highlighted)

Comment: Thank you, three  questions with that. 
1) The row runs through A to AB; I take it do it for all the columns?

Comment: 2) Do I have to do this every time I use the worksheet? 3) Would a VBA locking the word wrap from engaging be better? If I just simply lock the row then I have to have another VBA just to use the macro buttons on a protected sheet?

Comment: No problem at all, to answer your questions;    1) I would apply it to all columns just to be safe (you can simply click on the row header to highlight the entire row).    2) Once the "Wrap Text" is disabled, you can just save the workbook and it shouldn't be a problem again.    3) I don't think using VBA would be necessary, however you could protect the sheet (from the "Review" tab) which would grey out the "Wrap Text" button and prevent it from being pressed again